# How to insert a django user's username in the path via a view?

Tags: python, django

I am a naive Django user. 
I have implemented a sign-in functionality with the Django user model. Here's my project's urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf.urls import url
from signin import views as viewsignin

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('signin.urls')),
    path('dashboard/',include('dashboard.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Here's my dashboard app's urls.py, which gives a path to the dashboard view once a user logs in.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('dashboard/',views.dashboard,name='dashboard'),
]
```

Here's a snippet of views.py of my signin app:

```
def signin(request):
    message={}
    if request.method=='POST':
        user =authenticate(username=request.POST['email'],password=request.POST['pwd'])
        print(user,request.POST['email'],request.POST['pwd'])
        if user:
            print("User exists")
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                USER = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
                return redirect('dashboard)#I HAVE A PROBLEM HERE
        else:
            message['cred_err']=True

    return render(request,'signin/signin.html',context=message)
```

What I want is that when signing in is successful, the path of dashboard shows the username of the user who logged in. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You should add a parameter to the `dashboard` view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/<str:username>',views.dashboard,name='dashboard'),
]
```

then you can redirect to the dashboard with the username as:

```
def signin(request):
    message = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['email'],password=request.POST['pwd'])
        if user and user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('dashboard', username=user.username)
        else:
            message['cred_err'] = True
    return render(request,'signin/signin.html',context=message)
```